# Ask a recruiter for feedback

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, hiring-process, ethics

I've been interviewed and accepted for a job.

However, the paperwork can take from 2 to 3 months (legal stuff).

When I asked my recruiter on when to submit my resignation (note that my notice period is three months non negotiable), he said and I quote:

"It's premature now, we still don't have clear vision on the paperwork".

It has been around a month when I last asked him about updates, all hi said was that he is on vacation and he will get back to me within 5 days. since then I didn't get anything back from him.

You think I should remind him? I don't want be nagging him off. and if I have to remind him, how do you think I should approach it?

Now this is giving me headaches, because I'm refusing some good offers and I don't have clear vision on what's going on.

Comment: How many days his it been since the end of his "5 days" has elapsed?

Comment: @Snow Around a month

Comment: @Carcosa, This is not a follow up, I got the offer, I'm asking about post offer, thank you

Comment: Paint us a picture on why 'legal stuff' would take 2 to 3 months.  This sounds very odd, and there are likely details to be stated that would be necessary for us to give a decent answer.

Comment: @JimHorn, because It's a job in a different country. note that the notice period is also three months (I forgot to mention it)

Comment: Ok.  Perhaps I shouldn't comment then as I don't have experience working in another country and the paperwork requirements to do that, but in my distant opinion it seems like there's a whole bunch of issues that could arise in 2-3 months that would cause this process to delay, and really prevent you from doing rock-solid long term planning.  Good luck.

Comment: If the contract is not signed, the offer does not really count. Stop rejecting other offers (unless you're independently wealthy and don't need that income). You should keep on interviewing.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, you suggest I shouldn't reach back, and just keep on interviewing ? and yes I didn't sign a contract.

Comment: @John, did you never negotiate with the new job on when you are going to start?  This whole situation sounds very odd, new employers typically like to know when you are going to start, and from what I see you would have no way to provide that.

Comment: @John, No, of course, you should reach back. You should do both, reach back and continue interviewing. Until you have a signed contract with a start date, you have nothing. On a side-note, you should also look for reviews of the company made by former employees and job-hunters.

Comment: @raterus nop we didn't, but it seem very complicated, between the paperwork time and my notice period It could easily go up to 6months which very unpredictable.

Comment: StephanBranczyk, JimHorn thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, 
until you have signed contract, you should be able to proceed with any leads.